# Как запустить Docker приложение на Windows?

Tags: windows, nginx, docker, docker-compose

Docker скачан с официального сайта https://docs.docker.com/desktop/windows/install/ и использует WSL 2 в качестве бэкэнда. Установлен правильно, так как приложение hello-docker (или что-то такое) запускается. Есть докер приложение, которое нужно развернуть на винде. (Заранее отмечу, что в убунту докер приложение запустилось и работает исправно). Для этого я в папке с проектом запускаю команду `docker-compose build`, затем `docker-compose up -d`. `docker-compose ps` показывает что все контейнеры запущены.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Затем в браузере по адресу http://0.0.0.0:112/ ожидаю увидеть запущенное приложение, но вместо этого вижу (адрес и порт верные):
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Несколько раз переустанавливал докер, безуспешно.

В чем может быть причина?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: 0.0.0.0 означает, что докер слушает все сетевые интерфейсы, этот адрес нельзя использовать для соединения. Используйте 127.0.0.1 или другой ip адрес этого компьютера.

Comment: @Roman-StopRUaggressioninUA спасибо большое, приложение запустилось